# Functions on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I am learning about diff geometry and I have a question about ways of defining a function on a manifold. So if we think about manifolds in general we can define a chart on it. Then, through composition of a function and a chart we can analyze this function. My question is this. How can we define a function in the first place since it is on points P which need not be numbers. Dont we need to define the function on a chart in order for it to be defined on a manifold? And dont we then need to define a manifold through charts also? But in order for it to be defined properly we have to look for chart independent ptoperties which are read off the charts... I am confused.

Comment: What is a definition of function?

Comment: @Anubhav Mukherjee Map from manifold to R.

Answer (score 3):

I like your question, since I believe it is connected to one of the core topics of differential geometry.
Being not an expert, I can only give you my humble opinion on it, which is better expressed by a few questions, rather than long answers...

**Abstract vs. concrete functions...**

For sets $X, Y$, a function $f: X \to Y$ assigns a value $f(x)$ for each $x \in X$.
But if $X$ is large, we may want to use efficient ways to express $f(x)$ in terms of $x$.

To define a function on a manifold, we just need to assignment a value $f(p)$ for all $p \in \mathcal M$. (Which maybe also satisfied other conditions, e.g. smoothness.) If such an assignment is given, it will be automatically coordinate-free, since we did never toughed the charts to define it. That's the reason why we like this approach for abstract purposes.

But since our human brain has only finite memory, 
this method is a bit unpractical if we want to do calculations etc.

**How can we practically define functions on manifolds**

1. **Gobal chart:** If we have a global chart $h: \mathcal M \to \mathbb R^n$, then we can define a function $f = \tilde f \circ h$, with $\tilde f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ being a smooth function.

   Similary, we might use embeddings $e: \mathcal M \to \mathbb R^N$ to define a function for example on submanifolds of $\mathbb R^N$. 
   This is for example commonly used to define maps on submanifolds ($\mathrm{GL}(n)$, $\mathrm{SO}(n)$, ...) of the manifold of matrices $\mathrm{Mat}(n\times n)$.
2. **Finitely many charts:** For two charts $h_1: \mathcal U \to \mathbb R^n$ and $h_2: \mathcal V \to \mathbb R^n$, we may define $f_1 : \mathcal U \to \mathbb R$ and $f_2 : \mathcal V \to \mathbb R$ as above, but then $f_1 = f_2$ must be assured on the intersection of the chart domains, i.e. for all $p \in \mathcal U \cap \mathcal V$.
3. **Implicit definitions:**
   It is sometimes still possible to calculate on manifolds, without having an explicit formula for a function.

   1. **Solutions of (partial) differential equations:**
      Assume, we can define a differential equation on a manifold.

      For example the Laplace equation $\Delta u = 0$ (with some boundary conditions, for example constant values on 'some' boundaries). Then we can define a map $u(p)$, by claiming that it is the unique solution of the partial differential equation. In particular, it is sufficient to provide a finite amount of data, to define the function! If the manifold has two boundaries, we just need to pick two numbers and $u$ is defined (if the PDE is well-defined, of course)!
      With this function $u$, we can continue to work, since we have (implicit) information about the function $u$ as well, which is sufficient for many tasks.

      But the examples don't stop here: We have the geodesic equation (and ODE), or Hamiltons equations etc...

      *Of course there is a hidden trap: To define a differential equation, say $\dot x(t) = F(x(t))$ on a manifold, we need a vector field $F$, which is 
      again a function $F: \mathcal M \to T \mathcal M$.*

      *But in important special cases, we know a little bit about $T \mathcal M$, which allows us to define, maybe implicitly, interesting functions of that type.
      (For example if $\mathcal M$ is a Lie group, then we can define one value $F(1) \in T_1 \mathcal M$. Now Lie groups are super cool and for each point $p$ there is a meaningful map $T \lambda_p : T_1 \mathcal M \to T_p \mathcal M$. This allows us to define $F(p) = D \lambda_p F(1)$. Expressed in coordinates, this map may not look like a constant map, and the solutions $x(t)$ are also somehow interesting.)*

**At the end...**
It is good to ask these equations! And be patient with the theory. Differential geometry need some time to feel natural, but after a while you will see that numbers, charts and coordinates are sometimes false friends. Spaces are often quite nonlinear!

EDIT:

**Concrete Example:**

We use a function $f: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R: (x,y,z) \mapsto x^2+y^4+z^2$.

Then we define $\mathcal M := f^{-1}(\{1\})$. This is indeed a manifold by the constant rank theorem, since $\mathrm{rk}(\mathrm{D} f(p)) = 1$, for all points $p \in \mathcal M$.

But we also have an embedding $\mathcal M \to \mathbb R^3: p=(x,y,z) \mapsto (x,y,z)$.

Therefore I can choose a function on $\mathbb R^3$, say
$$
\tilde f(x,y,z) = \sin(x) \cdot \exp(y)^{z^2}
$$
and define
$$
f(p) = \tilde f \circ e = \tilde f(x,y,z).
$$

As you see, we did not directly use the charts of $\mathcal M$, but only implicit information about $\mathcal M$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer man...so, would you say that abstract manifold is actually defined through its charts?

Comment: Because, you see, I have a problem. I used to think its all clear, you know, you define some coordinet axes and than put some numbers on space points, in 3d physical space eg. But then it ocured to me, where and how should I put the axes and what are these axes exactly?

Comment: Even more so, if you try to chart a space time manifold which is actually our physical space....torsion free, 4d manifold lalaalala...

Comment: I added a concrete example, which does not use charts directly.  

About the charts: (I agree with the replies from Federico.) Yes, charts are part of the differentiable structure, which is needed to define a manifold. **But,** we do not need to know them explicitly and even if, the idea is to think about points of a manifold to be not just points, which we can described in a linear manner by a few numbers.

About physical spaces: Is there one or are there many (equally important) charts for physical spaces?
Some calculus laws with x-y-z coordinates are simply not true for general charts.

Answer (score 1):

> How can we define a function in the first place since it is on points P which need not be numbers.

Functions need not be defined only on "numbers", whatever that means.
Functions can be defined on arbitrary sets, in particular manifolds. For instance, given a manifold $M$, you can consider $f:M\to\mathbb R$ defined as $f(p)=0$ for every $p\in M$. Also notice that charts are actually functions $M\supset U\to\mathbb R^d$, so I don't understand why you are ok with them but not with other functions.

Comment: yes I agree that you can say it is zero everywhere, but that is not the point. How can you define in an exact way something more complicated?

Comment: What do you mean? $M^S=\{f:M \to S\}$ is a well defined set for every $M$ and $S$.

Comment: Regarding charts, yes, I am aware of them being maps from a manifold M to Rd, but not to R. Nevertheless, it still confuses me. How exactly do you chart a manifold?

Comment: There can be plenty of ways to describe any specific function.

Comment: For instance, $S^2\subset\mathbb R^3$ can be endowed with a manifold structure. But since it is also already embedded inside $\mathbb R^3$, you can also just take any function defined on the ambient space and restrict it.

Comment: For instance, you can take $x^2+\log(1+y^2) z-e^x$ defined on $S^2$ where $(x,y,z)$ are the coordinates of the ambient space $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Yes, that holds for any subset of Rdand with any Rd I dont have any problems. But, these are not only manifolds and some of them have just poinst...so what do you do? Define a value for each point? In what way?

Comment: Another procedure is taking a covering set of charts $(U_i,\phi_i)$ and fix some functions $f_i:\phi_i(U_i)\subset\mathbb R^d\to S$ with the compatibility property that $f_i\circ\phi_i = f_j\circ\phi_j$ in the common domain. This means that you can "glue" them together, becaue in the common domain a unique value is well defined.

Comment: Ok, so you would define a functionon some subset of Rd using charts...that is what I wrote in my question. So now, can we say that a manifold is defined through itc charts?

Comment: What do you mean by "a manifold is defined through it charts"?

Comment: If you have a function $g_i$ defined on $U_i$ for every $i$ and they agree in common domains, then there is a function $g$ defined on the whole manifold. Where is the problem?

Comment: Well, you say that a procedure is to first define some chart maps with good properties and then to define a function on a manifold...but you are actually defining it on chart target set, Rd, so in a way, your manifold is defined through its maping to Rd by charts?

Comment: Yes, an abstract manifold is just an underlying space plus a collection of charts. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold.

Comment: The charts are a fundamental component of the definition of a manifold. You can not just look at the underlying space. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold.

Comment: So, from a way these charts are overlaped and from their singularities  we can conclude stuff?

Comment: Yes, I know man...i know the definition of a manifold. So, yes, it is a toplogical space which can be maped onto Rd, and sorts of maps we can use actually define it then?

Comment: In particular, you can use the chart to define objects locally and then glue them together once you check that they satisfy compatibility conditions. For functions (without any regularity), this is trivial: just verify that the several pieces coincide where they are both defined